# How to prevent partitions from being mounted automatically in Linux(Mint)?

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, unmount

I have a Linux(Mint)/Windows dual boot PC. 
Checked **/etc/fstab** and their are no entries for the Windows and System Reserved partition. 
Don't really understand how it's happening.
Any other place I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps ntfs-config utility does this automounting. 
See http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/automount_ntfs.html for additional information.

Comment: Yep you got it, I forgot I installed this the other day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`cd /etc`

`sudo find | grep autofs`

Check that file, it is autofs mounting them. Sry I would go into detail but I'm driving...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently while installing Mint over a system that'd previously been running Ubuntu.  Would be nice if someone could confirm, but it appears to have been caused by the Mint installer automounting the swap portion of that partition.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Linux is aware of the other partition(s) but does not mount them for you. To see what partitions exist, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

which lists out the partitions. You should see some NTFS ones, note which device(s) they are. On my system it was /dev/sda2.
Again from the terminal, create a folder for the mountpoint under Linus, thus:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/windows
```

Now you add the NTFS partition as an entry to the File System Table file, /etc/fstab.  Depending on what editor came with your Linux or what you installed/like, edit the fstab file. My example shows gedit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

At the end, add a new line for the NFTS partition, separate fields with tab:

```
/dev/sda2  /mnt/windows  ntfs  umask=000,defaults  0  0
```

Save the changes and close the editor.
Next time you restart the NTFS partition should mount automatically and you can access the files through the folder /mnt/windows.
To mount this now, type in:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you.  For formatting help, including a summary of Markdown syntax, see http://superuser.com/editing-help.